# PHP IPN Works in Simulator, but not Sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

So, I have a script, paypal-listener.php. It uses a PaypalIPN class to verify the payment. Now, when I use the simulator, it says the handshake was successful, and it even puts in the mock-info into my database. However, the moment I attempt to use it on the sandbox, my script fails. This is the HTML:

```
<form action="<?php echo $pplink; ?>" method="post">

<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@inmatescribes.com">

<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="10.00">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1-
<?php echo $row['customer_id'] ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="transaction_subject" 
value="1,000 Credit Fill Up">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="1,000 Credit Fill Up">

<!--Custom code for the site user's ID-->
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="
<?php echo $_SESSION['customer_id']; ?>">

<input type="hidden" name="return" 
value="http://www.i-scribes.com/inmatescribes/payment-complete.php">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" 
value="http://www.i-scribes.com/inmatescribes/payment-cancel.php">


<input type="image" name="submit" border="0" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US
/i/btn/png/btn_buynow_107x26.png" alt="Buy Now">
<img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" 
src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/
en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

My PHP Class is:

```
<?php
class PaypalIPN
{
    /**
     * @var bool $use_sandbox  -- Indicates if the sandbox endpoint is used.
     */
    private $use_sandbox = false;
    /**
     * @var bool $use_local_certs Indicates if the local certificates are used.
     */
    private $use_local_certs = true;
    /** Production Postback URL */
    const VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Sandbox Postback URL */
    const SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI = 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation was successful */
    const VALID = 'VERIFIED';
    /** Response from PayPal indicating validation failed */
    const INVALID = 'INVALID';
    /**
     * Sets the IPN verification to sandbox mode (for use when testing,
     * should not be enabled in production).
     * @return void
     */
    public function useSandbox()
    {
        $this->use_sandbox = true;
    }
    /**
     * Sets curl to use php curl's built in certs (may be required in some
     * environments).
     * @return void
     */
    public function usePHPCerts()
    {
        $this->use_local_certs = false;
    }
    /**
     * Determine endpoint to post the verification data to.
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPaypalUri()
    {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) {
            return self::SANDBOX_VERIFY_URI;
        } else {
            return self::VERIFY_URI;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Verification Function
     * Sends the incoming post data back to PayPal using the cURL library.
     *
     * @return bool
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function verifyIPN()
    {
        if ( ! count($_POST)) {
            throw new Exception("Missing POST Data");
        }
        $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
        $myPost = array();
        foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
            $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
            if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
                if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
                    if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                        $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
                $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
        }
        // Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
        $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
        $get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
        if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
            $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
        }
        foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
            if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
            } else {
                $value = urlencode($value);
            }
            $req .= "&$key=$value";
        }
        // Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
        $ch = curl_init($this->getPaypalUri());
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        // This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.
        if ($this->use_local_certs) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if ( ! ($res)) {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $http_code = $info['http_code'];
        if ($http_code != 200) {
            throw new Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        // Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
        if ($res == self::VALID) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}`

And my actual listener is:

`<?php
namespace Listener;

require( 'PaypalIPN.php' );
require('db-connect.php');

use PaypalIPN;

$ipn = new PaypalIPN();

// Use the sandbox endpoint during testing.
$ipn->useSandbox();

$verified = $ipn->verifyIPN();

if ( $verified ) {

    $array = $_POST;

    $arrayDump = json_encode( $array );

    file_put_contents( 'payment-record.txt', $arrayDump );

    // Now lets get those files back out.

    $fileContents = file_get_contents( 'payment-record.txt' );

    // Put them back in a usable array

    $pp_array = json_decode( $fileContents, true );


    // Now we need to decode that string...

    $vals = array();

    // Now lets get the item number and customer ID by exploding that string from "custom"; this can be anything we like, and in most instances, it will be customer_id and product_id
    // Or, as we call them, "package_id"'s 

    $item_info = $pp_array[ 'item_number1' ];

    // Split these two strings from "item_number"-- the first number is the package id, the second is the customer_id

    $strings = explode( "-", $item_info );

    // Get the package # that was bought -- correlated to "paypal_packages" table and row "package_id".

    $package_bought = $strings[ 0 ];

    // Get the customer ID

    $cid = $strings[ 1 ];

    // Enter all the relevant info into this array.


    $vals[ 'customer_id' ] = $cid;
    $vals[ 'amount_paid' ] = $pp_array[ 'mc_gross' ];
    $vals[ 'pp_payer_id' ] = $pp_array[ 'payer_id' ];
    $vals[ 'package_bought' ] = $package_bought;
    $vals[ 'buyer_email' ] = $pp_array[ 'payer_email' ];
    $vals[ 'paypal_fee' ] = $pp_array[ 'payment_fee' ];
    $vals[ 'buyer_l_name' ] = $pp_array[ 'last_name' ];
    $vals[ 'buyer_f_name' ] = $pp_array[ 'first_name' ];

    // I have my custom field set to be the actual customer who made the order for the inamte. This is from the session variable.
    $vals[ 'online_customer_id' ] = intval( $pp_array[ 'custom' ] );

    // If the payment is complete, make it so on the database.

    if ( $pp_array[ 'payment_status' ] == "Completed" ) {

        $vals[ 'pp_payment_status' ] = 1;

    }


    $vals[ 'finished' ] = 0;
    $vals[ 'array_dump' ] = $arrayDump;
    $vals[ 'date_entered' ] = mktime();

    $db->insertRecords( "paypal_payments", $vals );

}

// Reply with an empty 200 response to indicate to paypal the IPN was received correctly.
header( "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" );

?>
```

Comment: It might be your `VERIFY_URI` urls. They seem a little old.